# Splashscreen will not move to next page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have been reading much about Xamarin for sometime and how to make a splash screen. I am quite new to something like this and hence i wanted to ask on here, Why is the splash screen not redirecting to the login page in the Emulator'

i am using Visual Studio 2019, I added a new folder drawable-hdpi and then added the images to it to be used inside the xaml. Now what? it does not redirect!

Here is what my code looks like

**Splash screen Xaml (MainPage.xaml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="VisitorMan.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#fff">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10">
        <Image Source="splash_logo.png" x:Name="imgLogo" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The corresponsing MainPage.xaml.cs File Looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace VisitorMan
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Animate();
        }

        public async Task Animate() 
        {
            imgLogo.Opacity = 0;
            await imgLogo.FadeTo(1, 4000);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
    }
}
```

The Login Page which shows the username and password **(LoginPage.xaml)** Looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="VisitorMan.LoginPage"
             BackgroundColor="#fff">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image Source="splash_logo.png" x:Name="imgLogo" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
            <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#ff77D065"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The splashscreen is just standstill and does not redirect to the Login Page. Could there be something i am missing?

Comment: Hi, I have checked shared code in my local project , there is no problem. You can share the screenshot of `Resources` folder in Android . Make sure the name of image is correct used in Forms and be reaally add to project.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, it does not redirect to the main Login screen from the splashscreen. hence I concluded , thats what the worry is

Comment: Okey , have a try with updating VS and Xamarin Forms to the latest version . If also not , share sample project here , will check it .

Comment: Still the same, here is the download link https://gofile.io/?c=GYDOqW

Comment: i use Visual Studio 2019 and Android Studio

Comment: Thanks for sharing , I will check it .

Comment: Hi  Jin, the reason has been found , you also need to update Nuget Packages to the lastest version .You can have a look at answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried shared sample , the problem is that you need to **update nuget packages** (*especially version of Xamarin.Forms*) of project **to the latest version**.

**Right click** Solution of project , choose **Manage Nuget Packages For Solution...**

[image]

After Updated :

[image]

The effect :

[image]

Comment: You the man. Update did work for me. I guess I would have to be on the lookout for that the next time.

Comment: @Jin Yeah , sometimes version of Forms can be the reason after updating VS .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check but you can try this

```
public async Task Animate() 
{
    imgLogo.Opacity = 0;
    await imgLogo.FadeTo(1, 4000);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
       Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
    });
}
```

Comment: Well it does not show the splash screen it just moves straight to the login page, i wanted it to show the splash screen and then on to the login screen